# German Employment/Work Visa application submission in Germany and other countries

Tags: working-visas, germany, employment, foreign-employment, german-citizens

I am an Indian Citizen and received a job offer from a German Employer (In Munich) to start working as a Software Engineer.
They have offered me a permanent job in Germany and shared a signed job offer which i should use for my Visa application.

But unfortunately, from German Embassy in New Delhi India there is a huge waiting of appointment for document submission. I am not able to get a quick appointment for work visa as all appointment are booked until December 4 (as per today and keep growing each day).

My job in Germany starts in July and this is really frustrating that even tough i have everything ready for documentation but still i can't start my job for visa issues.

Can anybody suggest :

a) Is there a way my employer can initiate a work visa for me? BTW I have asked my employer but they are not sure about it as they never did it in past.

b) I have a resident permit of Norway (which is valid till OCT-2019).

1. Is there a way i can initiate it from Norway? (please note that i have completed only 4 months in Norway).
2. Can i travel to Germany (based on my resident permit of Norway) and submit the work visa application directly in Munich?

Please help and suggest. If you have any alternate suggestions, feel free to share.

Thanks

Comment: 2. is only possible for **citizens** of a limited selection of countries (EU/EFTA, US/CAN, Japan/South Korea, Australia/NZ — IIRC)

Comment: @Janka : Yes, but i can enter in Germany via Norway(as a resident card for travel purpose is valid for all Schengen areas). My query is that , can i apply directly in Germany for my work permit with valid documents?

Comment: No. That's why I emphasized **citizens**. No idea about 1. That may actually work. Ask the German Embassy in Oslo.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience:

a) Your employer can't initiate the process, they can only provide you with all the documents, including working contract, which are required for the application.

b)

1. Look at [this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/how-to-prepare-for-german-visa-work-permit-embassy-interview) question. Basically you can apply in an embassy or consulate in other country (as I did). I'm not sure though if you can do it without actually living/having an address in the country where you have residence permit at least because you'll have to to be waiting there and maybe bring other documents per request after applying.
2. is less likely, because the application from inside the country already requires a German address and confirmation from your landlord (Wohnraumnachweis and rental contract) and be registered there. That's why you need the national visa first.

The best way is to write an E-mail to the embassy/consulate with your questions about the possibility and the list of documents required. This information might be more trustworthy and clear than what you can find on official websites.

This is the way I know. Maybe it differs depending on circumstances and permit/employment types.