# How to prepare for German visa/work permit embassy interview

Tags: working-visas, germany, interview

I'm a non-EU citizen, and I have a job contract to work as a software engineer for a German company in Berlin.

I've already prepared all the legal documents. However, I'm really concerned about the consulate interview as it's gonna be in a different country, because there's no German embassy in my country.

What kind of question they will ask (the general purpose of their question about what)? Dose the fact that I have to make the interview in different county add more challenging to these questions? Will they ask to provide additional documents to the ones listed on the consulate website?

If someone has similar experience, it would be appreciated if he/she could share it with us, as I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Since the country where you are applying from is handling applications from multiple countries, they must have a bigger document check-list compared to other embassies and those documents will serve as a proof for everything written on your application. When you go for an in-person interview, generally they try to ensure if you really are the person who is on the documents, they might ask a few questions related to your field as well, so be prepared. Also, the processing time could be longer than the estimated time since that's a different country. And lastly, I wish you best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation as you a couple of years ago. The questions they asked were mostly about the documents. There was nothing tricky or anything. I applied for a German visa from the US and I'm not a US citizen. I just had to show a valid residence permit for the US and the rest of the documents were the same as mentioned on their website.

The questions they asked were really basic like "What will your income be?", "How will you find an accommodation" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got my visa in the German general consulate in Amsterdam (being NOT-EU citizen, but living in the Netherlands). I didn't have to attend any special interview and all the conversation was about the application form itself (all the info is already there), working contract and salary (as a requirement for the Blue Card).

Make sure to make a call or better send an E-mail before the appointment to ask for the actual list of the documents required for the desired visa type (normal working visa or the one for the further Blue Card application in my case). I noticed that the list can fluctuate depending not only on location, but also on a person whom you will deal with. The same happens in the governmental organisations inside of the country.